# Help with Test Classes for Apex Classes

Tags: apex, unit-test

I am having trouble with getting one of the Classes to get Code Coverage. Below is the Code:

```
public class Match 
{                
    @TestVisible public List<Common> Common {get; set;}            
}
```

Below is the Common Apex Class that is being referenced by my Match Class:

```
@TestVisible public class Common {

    public String Address {get; set;}
    public String City {get; set;}
    public String FirstName {get; set;}
    public String Id {get; set;}
    public String LastName {get; set;}
    public String MiddleInitial {get; set;}
    public String Phone {get; set;}
    public String PostalCode {get; set;}
    public String RuleName {get; set;}
    public String Score {get; set;}
    public String StateProvince{get; set;}
    public String CompanyName {get; set;}
    public Integer CorporateEmployeesSizeActual{get; set;}      
    public String CorporateEmployeesSizeRange{get; set;}       
    public Integer CorporateSalesVolumeActual{get; set;}    
    public String CorporateSalesVolumeRange{get; set;}    
    public String CreditRatingScore{get; set;}
    public String Gender{get; set;}     
    public Integer LocationEmployeesSizeActual{get; set;}       
    public String LocationEmployeesSizeRange{get; set;}       
    public String PrimaryNaics{get; set;}       
    public String PrimarySic{get; set;}       
    public String Title{get; set;}

    public String BusinessType{get; set;}                        
    public String Franchise{get; set;}   
    public String LocationSalesVolumeActual{get; set;}   
    public String LocationSalesVolumeRange{get; set;}  
    public String TickerSymbol{get; set;}                     

}
```

The Test Class I have so far looks like this but I get an error 
Illegal assignment from Common to List:

```
@IsTest
private class TestClassess
{
    static testmethod void testMatch()
    {   
        Match obj = new Match();

        Common cmn = new Common();
        cmn.Address = 'z';

        obj.Common = cmn;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this is not my code but I do need to create a Test Class for it.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks!
Martijn

Comment: In your test class `obj.Common = cmn;` is invalid. `obj.Common` expecting `List<Common>` but you are assigning a variable of type `Common`

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that you don't need the @TestVisible annotation on public classes and members: if they are public, they are visible already. More importantly, your test is not actually asserting anything. The purpose of a test is not to provide coverage, but to test behaviour, which is done via asserts

Answer (score 2):

In your test class `obj.Common = cmn;` is invalid. `obj.Common` expecting `List<Common>` but you are assigning a variable of type `Common`. Update your code something as below where it's in type of `List<Common>`

```
@IsTest
private class TestClassess
{
    static testmethod void testMatch()
    {   
        Match obj = new Match();

        List<Common> commonList = new List<Common>();
        Common cmn = new Common();
        cmn.Address = 'z';

        commonList.add(cmn);

        obj.Common = commonList;
    }
}
```